# Using Flask/Jinja to dynamically insert InfoWindow to Markers (Google Maps API)

Tags: python, google-maps, flask, geolocation, jinja2

I am calling the Google API in order to get a location of the nearest EV stations using Flask. I am able to pull the coordinates and create markers to place on the map. I cannot, however, determine how to add the InfoWindow to each marker correctly after reviewing the documentation.

Currently, my map populates with the markers correctly inserted. I am looping in my script,creating and adding the event listener to each marker that will open the InfoWindow when clicked. The problem is the info window is only visible on one marker, regardless of what marker I click. So, the event listeners work in that you click and something happens, it's just that it's only anchoring to one location. Most answers I've stumbled upon on SO don't seem to address this in Flask, so it's unclear if this is a misuse of Flask or some other logic I'm missing.

**main.py**

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    lat_long = {'lat': [],'long': []}
    # Fetch nearest stations based on current coordinates 
    if request.method == "GET":
        req = requests.get(f'https://developer.nrel.gov/api/alt-fuel-stations/v1/nearest.json?api_key={config.stations_key}&fuel_type=E85,ELEC&latitude={my_location[0]}&longitude={my_location[1]}&limit=200').json()
        data = req['fuel_stations']
        length = len(req)

        # Obtain station latitude/longitude 
        for el in range(len(data)): 
            lat_long['lat'].append(data[el]['latitude'])
            lat_long['long'].append(data[el]['longitude'])
        llen = len(lat_long['long'])

    return render_template('base.html', data=data, length=length, gkey = config.gkey,
                           my_location=my_location, lat_long=lat_long, llen=l
```

**base.html**

```
 <script type="text/Javascript">
  var map;
  // Create map 
  function initMap(){
    markers = []
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      center: {lat: {{my_location[0]}}, lng: {{my_location[1]}}},
      zoom: 13
    })
    // Place location markers 
     
    {% for el in range(llen) %}
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "Test", 
        ariaLabel: "Label"
      });
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat: {{lat_long['lat'][el]}}, lng: {{lat_long['long'][el]}}}, 
        map: map,
        label: "Coords"
      });
       // console.log(marker.position.lat)
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", () => {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);   
        });
    {% endfor %}
    // Create click event 
  }
  initMap()
 </script>
```

I've tried adding the Listener inside my loop right after the marker is created, and anchoring the InfoWindow to the marker. I've tried outside the loop as well but this returns nothing.